# Undo check-in in RTC change-set

Tags: ibm-rad, rational-team-concert

I'm working on a project with RAD using RTC. I'm a rookie to this so the problem is I checked-in by mistake some classes that were under "unsolved". I don't know how to reverse this process. I moved the classes to another change-set because I didn't want them into the previous one, I added a comment on each class, so they are technically back to unsolved, but I don't know how to remove the new change-set without losing the actual changes on the files.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and [move a file from outgoing changeset back to unresolved](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/136040/how-to-move-a-file-from-outgoing-changeset-back-to-unresolved)

> Use the "Undo" action on the file change to remove it from the change set and revert it to an earlier state.